# How can I see dmesg output as it changes?

Tags: linux, command-line, logs, dmesg

I'm writing a device driver that prints error message into *ring buffer* dmesg output.
I want to see the output of `dmesg` as it changes.

How can I do this?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/289239/is-it-possible-to-tail-f-the-output-of-dmesg

Answer (score 301, accepted):

Relatively recent `dmesg` versions [provide a follow option](http://karelzak.blogspot.com/2012/09/util-linux-222.html) (`-w`, `--follow`) which works analogously to `tail -f`.

Thus, just use following command:

```
$ dmesg -wH
```

(`-H`, `--human` enables user-friendly features like colors, relative time)

Those options are available for example in Fedora 19.

Comment: Nice find! Gentoo doesn't grok `-H` but otherwise spot-on

Comment: The user space tools need to be version 2.22+. Ubuntu users have to wait for version 14.10 "utopic"

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't grok -w  - need to use watch (below)

Comment: Wow a sysadmin answer that uses --descriptively-named-flags instead of cryptic single-character flags. BRAVO, SIR. BRAVO.

Comment: `-w` should work in every version of Ubuntu from Utopic (14.10) onwards.  (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+publishinghistory suggests early Utopic packages were for 2.20, but reached 2.25 by the time it was released.)

Comment: coool! add -T for real HumanReadable timestamps under centos/fedora.

Comment: Another option is `journalctl -x -t kernel -f`. To my observation (and depending on the operating system), it provides the same information as `dmesg -wH`.

Comment: @Abdull or simply `journalctl -kf` -  however, keep in mind that journalctl usually requires root privileges for displaying system logs while dmesg doesn't. In addition, dmesg also works when journald isn't running.

Answer (score 66):

You can use the `watch` command which is intended exactly for things like this

```
watch -n 0.1 "dmesg | tail -n $((LINES-6))"
```

the `$((LINES-6))` part should make it fit nicely into your terminal.

Comment: If you use single quotes instead of double quotes (or escape the dollar sign), you'll to get a fresh value of $LINES for every invocation, so it will adjust if you change your terminal size.

Comment: Single quotes will inhibit variable expansion. Moreover, the variable is expanded only once in this example - upon invocation of `watch`. Thus it won't really change between invocations of `dmesg`. One would need to use a wrapper that would query the terminal state.

Comment: That's the whole point.  The single quotes prohibit the variable expansion when the shell passes the arguments to `watch`, therefore watch will execute the command with the variable expression in there, which will be expanded by the shell it invokes.  Each time.  Try it, it works.

Comment: Hmm, you are right - I assume `watch` uses `popen()`, which means another shell is spawned and the environment variable is then supplied by it (and thus updated on every execute run). Nice find.

Comment: The only option for macOS at this point as it the provided `dmseg` does not implement the `-w` flag.

Answer (score 17):

You can't really monitor the output of `dmesg` directly.

However, chances are high that your module is not printing directly into the ring-buffer of dmesg, but instead uses the kernel logging facilities (which will then be displayed by `dmesg`). If your `syslog` has some sane (e.g. default) settings, these messages will most likely also show up in the `kern.log` logfile.

So you can do something like:

```
 tail -f /var/log/kern.log
```

Comment: `/var/log/kern.log` is fairly Linux-specific.  For OpenBSD (and possibly others) the dmesg stuff gets logged in /var/log/messages.  Granted, some other stuff goes there too though.

Comment: `tail -f /var/log/{messages,kernel,dmesg,syslog}` via [superuser: is-it-possible-to-tail-f-the-output-of-dmesg](http://superuser.com/questions/289239/is-it-possible-to-tail-f-the-output-of-dmesg)

Answer (score 12):

You use `dmesg` to get log messages of the kernel.

The kernel itself logs into a ring buffer, i.e. just in memory.
Now all `dmesg` does is output the content of that ring buffer.
If you do `dmesg -c` it will also delete the ring buffer afterwards.

Therefore you could do something like `while true; do dmesg -c; sleep 1; done` to have something like the equivalent of a not working `dmesg|tail`. But this deletes the ring buffer and therefore needs root powers.

The other way is the file `/proc/kmsg` which allows a view on the ring buffer. You could do `tail -f /proc/kmsg`, but this is only allow to one process, and this is usually your logging daemon. - It's job is to read the messages and write it to real files (usually in /var/log) where they can be read. It can be configured to output all messages to a single file or different parts into different files. (But configuration depends on the logging daemon of your system.)

Therefore have a look at `/var/log` if there is any file which suits your needs and configure your logging daemon otherwise.

Comment: // , On the CEntOS 6 system I'm using, tailing and viewing /proc/kmsg produces no output. [~]$ sudo tail -f /proc/kmsg
♥%
[~]$ sudo cat /proc/kmsg
♥%
[~]$

Comment: `/dev/kmsg` is better.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294206/5132

Answer (score 11):

If you are using an embedded system, like [BusyBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox) that is common on systems like [OpenWrt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenWrt), it has very limited functionality and only 2-3 flags are supported.

If you want a quick and dirty way of printing dmesg output on the screen continually as events change, a simple Bash loop works fine. It's not ideal, but as I mentioned the BusyBox dmesg is missing a lot of functions. I find the following has the same effect when entered in to the command line:

```
$ while true; do dmesg -c ; sleep 1 ; done
```

You can quit the loop with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. The sleep 1 is to stop it battering the CPU needlessly, and the -c flag clears the buffer on each call so you don't see repeated output every second.

Comment: Really useful for debugging android.

Answer (score 8):

On systems that use `systemd` you can also:

```
# journalctl -kf
```

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10: ➜  ~  journalctl -kf
No journal files were found.

Answer (score 1):

Use these two commands from separate terminals:

1. `while true; do dmesg -c >> test.txt;sleep 1; done`
2. `tail -f test.txt`

It will achieve a similar result.

Comment: // , This basically instructs dmesg to append output to test.txt, right? 
And the second command just watches that test.txt file?

Comment: Thanks .. yes.. the 2nd command watches the changes to dmesg. cat /proc/kmsg can achieve the similar output but it doesn't save the logs to a file.