# Understand logging in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, syslog, rsyslog, syslog-ng

As I understand, Linux kernel logs to `/proc/kmsg` file(mostly hardware-related messages) and `/dev/log` socket? Anywhere else? Are other applications also able to send messages to `/proc/kmsg` or `/dev/log`? Last but not least, am I correct that it is the syslog daemon(*rsyslog*, *syslog-ng*) which checks messages from those two places and then distributes those to various files like `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/kern.log` or even central syslog server?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Simplified, it goes more or less like this:

The kernel logs messages (using the `printk()` function) to a ring buffer in kernel space.  These messages are made available to user-space applications in two ways: via the `/proc/kmsg` file (provided that `/proc` is mounted), and via the `sys_syslog` syscall.

There are two main applications that read (and, to some extent, can control) the kernel's ring buffer: `dmesg(1)` and `klogd(8)`.  The former is intended to be run on demand by users, to print the contents of the ring buffer.  The latter is a daemon that reads the messages from `/proc/kmsg` (or calls `sys_syslog`, if `/proc` is not mounted) and sends them to `syslogd(8)`, or to the console.  That covers the kernel side.

In user space, there's `syslogd(8)`.  This is a daemon that listens on a number of UNIX domain sockets (mainly `/dev/log`, but others can be configured too), and optionally to the UDP port 514 for messages.  It also receives messages from `klogd(8)` (`syslogd(8)` doesn't care about `/proc/kmsg`).  It then writes these messages to some files in `/log`, or to named pipes, or sends them to some remote hosts (via the `syslog` protocol, on UDP port 514), as configured in `/etc/syslog.conf`.

User-space applications normally use the `libc` function `syslog(3)` to log messages.  `libc` sends these messages to the UNIX domain socket `/dev/log` (where they are read by `syslogd(8)`), but if an application is `chroot(2)`-ed the messages might end up being written to other sockets, f.i. to `/var/named/dev/log`.  It is, of course, essential for the applications sending these logs and `syslogd(8)` to agree on the location of these sockets.  For these reason `syslogd(8)` can be configured to listen to additional sockets aside from the standard `/dev/log`.

Finally, the `syslog` protocol is just a datagram protocol.  Nothing stops an application from sending syslog datagrams to any UNIX domain socket (provided that its credentials allows it to open the socket), bypassing the `syslog(3)` function in `libc` completely.  If the datagrams are correctly formatted `syslogd(8)` can use them as if the messages were sent through `syslog(3)`.

Of course, the above covers only the "classic" logging theory.  Other daemons (such as `rsyslog` and `syslog-ng`, as you mention) can replace the plain `syslogd(8)`, and do all sorts of nifty things, like send messages to remote hosts via encrypted TCP connections, provide high resolution timestamps, and so on.  And there's also `systemd`, that is slowly phagocytosing the UNIX part of Linux.  `systemd` has its own logging mechanisms, but that story would have to be told by somebody else. :)

Differences with the *BSD world:

On *BSD there is no `klogd(8)`, and `/proc` either doesn't exist (on OpenBSD) or is mostly obsolete (on FreeBSD and NetBSD).  `syslogd(8)` reads kernel messages from the character device `/dev/klog`, and `dmesg(1)` uses `/dev/kmem` to decode kernel names.  Only OpenBSD has a `/dev/log`.  FreeBSD uses two UNIX domain sockets `/var/run/log` and `var/rub/logpriv` instead, and NetBSD has a `/var/run/log`.

Comment: nit: rsyslog is more popular now (default for Fedora, Debian), and it doesn't use a separate klogd.  Looks like syslog-ng doesn't (by preference) either.

Comment: @sourcejedi I haven't followed Linux all that closely in more than a few years now, but IIRC `rsyslog` doesn't use `klogd(8)` because its roots go way back, not because it recently made an explicit decision to do away with it.  My memory can be failing though.  Anyway, like I said, I was only trying to cover "classic" logging.

Comment: Because of these logs...Did you find any system performance issues?

Comment: @Thushi Yes: synchronous writing of logs for busy daemons can lead to I/O performance issues.  On the other hand, asynchronous writing of logs can lead to message loss.

Comment: @lcd047, @sourcejedi, Thanks for replies! I had one Debian 7 system with `rsyslogd` running and one Ubuntu 12.04  with `syslog-ng` running and they both had file `/proc/kmsg` open according to `lsof`, i.e. `klogd` was not used. Another interesting thing which I noticed is that log messages are stored in `/proc/kmsg` file if no syslog daemon is running and one can view those with for example `cat` or text editor. However, it's only possible to view those messages once because they disappear after viewing. Last but not least, executing `dmesg` does not clear the content of `/proc/kmsg` file.

Comment: @Martin `/proc/kmsg` is not a regular file, there is nothing "stored" there, rather it's just a view of the kernel's ring buffer.  You can read it with `cat` precisely because you have no `klogd(8)` running (should you run `klogd(8)`, `cat /proc/kmsg` would block).  `dmesg(1)` reads messages from `/dev/kmsg` rather than `/proc/kmsg`; and it can also clear the buffer if you tell it to.

Comment: `systemd has its own logging mechanisms, but that story would have to be told by somebody else. :)` -- Please you tell, you got talent :-)

Comment: Is the syslog protocol documented somewhere?

Comment: @MariusGedminas The syslog protocol is documented in RFC 5424 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5424)

Answer (score 92):

The other answer explains, as its author says, "classic logging" in Linux.  That's not how things work in a lot of systems nowadays.

### The kernel

The kernel mechanisms have changed.

The kernel generates output to an in-memory buffer.  Application softwares can access this in two ways.  The logging subsystem usually accesses it as a pseudo-FIFO named `/proc/kmsg`.  This source of log information cannot usefully be shared amongst log readers, because it is read-once.  If multiple processes share it, they each get only a part of the kernel log data stream.  It is also read-only.

The other way to access it is the newer `/dev/kmsg` character device.  This is a read-write interface that is shareable amongst multiple client processes.  If multiple processes share it, they all read the same complete data stream, unaffected by one another.  If they open it for write access, they can also inject messages into the kernel's log stream, as if they were generated by the kernel.

`/proc/kmsg` and `/dev/kmsg` provide log data in a non-RFC-5424 form.

### Applications

Applications have changed.

The GNU C library's `syslog()` function in the main attempts to connect to an `AF_LOCAL` datagram socket named `/dev/log` and write log entries to it.  (The BSD C library's `syslog()` function nowadays uses `/var/run/log` as the socket name, and tries `/var/run/logpriv` first.)  Applications can of course have their own code to do this directly.  The library function is just code (to open, connect, write to, and close a socket) executing in the application's own process context, after all.

Applications can also send RFC 5424 messages via UDP to a local RFC 5426 server, if one is listening on an `AF_INET`/`AF_INET6` datagram socket on the machine.

Thanks to pressure from the daemontools world over the past two decades, a lot of dæmons support running in a mode where they don't use the GNU `syslog()` C library function, or UDP sockets, but just spit their log data out to standard error in the ordinary Unix fashion.

### log management with nosh and the daemontools family in general

With the daemontools family of toolsets there's a lot of flexibility in logging.  But in general across the whole family the idea is that each "main" dæmon has an associated "logging" dæmon.  "main" dæmons work just like non-dæmon processes and write their log messages to standard error (or standard output), which the service management subsystem arranges to have connected via a pipe (which it holds open so that log data are not lost over a service restart) to the standard input of the "logging" dæmon.

All of the "logging" dæmons run a program that logs *somewhere*.  Generally this program is something like `multilog` or `cyclog` that reads from its standard input and writes (nanosecond timestamped) log files in a strictly size-capped, automatically rotated, exclusive-write, directory.  Generally, too, these dæmons all run under the aegises of individual dedicated unprivileged user accounts.

So one ends up with a largely distributed logging system, with each service's log data processed separately.

One *can* run something like `klogd` or `syslogd` or `rsyslogd` under a daemontools-family service management.  But the daemontools world realized many years ago that the service management structure with "logging" dæmons lends itself quite neatly to doing things in a simpler fashion.  There's no need to fan all of the log streams into one giant mish-mash, parse the log data, and then fan the streams back out to separate log files; and then (in some cases) bolt an unreliable external log rotation mechanism on the side.  The daemontools-family structure as part of its standard log management *already does* the log rotation, the logfile writing, and the stream separation.

Furthermore: The chain-loading model of dropping privileges with tools common across all services means that the logging programs have no need of superuser privileges; and the UCSPI model means that they only need to care about differences such as stream versus datagram transports.

The nosh toolset exemplifies this.  Whilst one *can* run `rsyslogd` under it, out of the box, and just manage kernel, `/run/log`, and UDP log input in the old way; it *also* provides more "daemontools native" ways of logging these things:

- a `klogd` service that reads from `/proc/kmsg` and simply writes that log stream to its standard error.  This is done by a simple program named `klog-read`.  The associated logging dæmon feeds the log stream on its standard input into a `/var/log/sv/klogd` log directory.
- a `local-syslog-read` service that reads datagrams from `/dev/log` (`/run/log` on the BSDs) and simply writes that log stream to its standard error.  This is done by a program named `syslog-read`.  The associated logging dæmon feeds the log stream on its standard input into a `/var/log/sv/local-syslog-read` log directory.
- a `udp-syslog-read` service that listens on the UDP syslog port, reads what it is sent to it and simply writes that log stream to its standard error.  Again, the program is `syslog-read`.  The associated logging dæmon feeds the log stream on its standard input into a `/var/log/sv/udp-syslog-read` log directory.
- (on the BSDs) a `local-priv-syslog-read` service that reads datagrams from `/run/logpriv` and simply writes that log stream to its standard error.  Again, the program is `syslog-read`.  The associated logging dæmon feeds the log stream on its standard input into a `/var/log/sv/local-priv-syslog-read` log directory.

The toolset also comes with an `export-to-rsyslog` tool that can monitor one or several log directories (using a system of non-intrusive *log cursors*) and send new entries in RFC 5424 form over the network to a designated RFC 5426 server.

### log management with systemd

systemd has a single monolithic log management program, `systemd-journald`.  This runs as a service managed by systemd.

- It reads `/dev/kmsg` for kernel log data.
- It reads `/dev/log` (a symbolic link to `/run/systemd/journal/dev-log`) for application log data from the GNU C library's `syslog()` function.
- It listens on the `AF_LOCAL` stream socket at `/run/systemd/journal/stdout` for log data coming from systemd-managed services.
- It listens on the `AF_LOCAL` datagram socket at `/run/systemd/journal/socket` for log data coming from programs that speak the systemd-specific journal protocol (i.e. `sd_journal_sendv()` et al.).
- It mixes these all together.
- It writes to a set of system-wide and per-user journal files, in `/run/log/journal/` or `/var/log/journal/`.
- If it can connect (as a client) to an `AF_LOCAL` datagram socket at `/run/systemd/journal/syslog` it writes journal data there, if forwarding to syslog is configured.
- If configured, it writes journal data to the kernel buffer using the writable `/dev/kmsg` mechanism.
- If configured, it writes journal data to terminals and the console device as well.

Bad things happen system-wide if this program crashes, or the service is stopped.

systemd itself arranges for the standard outputs and errors of (some) services to be attached to the `/run/systemd/journal/stdout` socket.  So dæmons that log to standard error in the normal fashion have their output sent to the journal.

This completely supplants klogd, syslogd, syslog-ng, and rsyslogd.

These are now required to be systemd-specific.  On a systemd system they don't get to be the server end of `/dev/log`.  Instead, they take one of two approaches:

- They get to be the server end of `/run/systemd/journal/syslog`, which (if you remember) `systemd-journald` attempts to connect and write journal data to.  A couple of years ago, one would have configured rsyslogd's `imuxsock` input method to do this.
- They read directly from the systemd journal, using a systemd-specific library that understands the binary journal format and that can monitor the journal files and directory for new entries being added.  Nowadays, one configures rsyslogd's `imjournal` input method to do this.

Comment: I was referred to your answer here during an exchange of comments for [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704833/why-can-journald-not-be-disabled/704835?noredirect=1#comment1333533_704835). WRT this part of your answer: *"Bad things happen system-wide if this program crashes, or the service is stopped."*  Am I correct in reading that as saying that systems using `systemd` will not run without `journald`? If so - why would someone design a logger that brings down the entire system if it fails?