# How do I append/prepend a timestamp to grep output?

Tags: grep, logs, timestamps, gawk, temperature

I am running a small linux server at home, and I am writing a script to log the temperature of the CPU cores every 5 seconds, but I need timestamps for it to be useful. So far I have something that saves the output of the `sensors` command into a file, and I have a command that prints the date and time. ***I just need to figure out how to combine those two.***

`sensors | grep ^Core* >> temps.log` saves temps in temps.log in following format:

```
Core 0:       +39.0°C  (high = +76.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +40.0°C  (high = +76.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

and for the date I can do `date +%m/%d/%y-%H:%M:%S` which returns

```
mm/dd/yy-hh:mm:ss
```

I googled around and saw someone suggesting the use of `gawk` but I have absolutely no idea how `gawk` works.

Comment: Great. So what is the question exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want to accomplish is to prepend the current date to every line that is output by grep. This is an easy task for a bash script:

```
sensors | grep ^Core |\
(
  DATE=$(date +%m/%d/%y-%H:%M:%S)
  while read LINE
  do
    echo "$DATE $LINE"
  done
) >> temps.log
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. Now I just need to put it into a loop so it keeps going until either the file gets to a certain size or it hits a certain number of lines.

Comment: 'collectd' is your friend. This daemon collect system metrics of your servers

Answer (score 11):

> a script to log […] every 5 seconds […] I need timestamps […] a loop […] the file gets to a certain size

You want a tool that takes as its input the log output of your main program, and that writes it to a size-capped log file, and adds timestamps.  Tools exist that do this and more.  The "more" that they do is automatic rotation of the log file that is also triggerable on demand, maintaining a size-capped *log directory* of current and old log files.

You have a choice of tools:

- Dan Bernstein's [`multilog`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/multilog.html) from daemontools
- Bruce Guenter's [`multilog`](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/multilog.8.html) from daemontools-encore
- Laurent Bercot's [`s6-log`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-log.html) from s6
- Gerrit Pape's [`svlogd`](http://smarden.org/runit/svlogd.8.html) from runit
- Wayne Marshall's [`tinylog`](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=tinylog.8) from perp
- My [`cyclog`](http://jdebp.info/Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/cyclog.xml) from nosh

Assume a long-running utility that prints your desired log output every few seconds, something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
# monitor-sensors
exec 2>&1
while true
do
sensors
sleep 5
done | grep --line-buffered -- '^Core'
```

Usage is as simple as:

- `monitor-sensors | cyclog ./temps`
- `monitor-sensors | multilog t ./temps`

and can be easily tweaked:

- `monitor-sensors | cyclog --max-file-size 32768 --max-total-size 1048576 ./temps`
- `monitor-sensors | s6-log t s32768 S1048576 ./temps`
- `monitor-sensors | multilog t s32768 n5 ./temps`

From here, using toolsets like daemontools-encore/runit/perp/s6/nosh, it is but a small step to moving the left and right hand sides of this pipe into `run` programs and running this as a linked pair of actual dæmons.

But they can all, also, handle being spun up for one-off output to existing log directories, if you just want to (say) perform one-off invocations from a command line.

Some of these tools can do other forms of timestamps, but they can all do TAI64N timestamps.  TAI64N timestamps are designed to be capable of nanosecond precision, albeit that some of the aforementioned do not quite implement this; are designed to quite happily cope with things like leap seconds, as long as your TZ database knows about them; and are trivial to `sort`, or even `sort -m`.

Convert from TAI64N timestamps to your current timezone's local time (or, given that it's just the `TZ` environment variable, an arbitrary timezone of your choosing) using tools such as:

- Dan Bernstein's [`tai64nlocal`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/tai64nlocal.html) from daemontools
- Bruce Guenter's [`tai64nlocal`](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/tai64nlocal.8.html) from daemontools-encore
- My [`tai64nlocal`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/tai64nlocal.html) from nosh

Watch such logs as they are written with:

- `tail -F`, albeit that `tail` has known problems when there are very speedy rotations. (This is one of several known problems with `tail`.  Other known problems including handling in-place truncation of log files that are rapidly followed by more log data.  This problem can be triggered by inferior systems such as `logrotate`.  Fortunately, the aforementioned tools do not truncate files once they are fully written and do not risk such additional `tail` problems.)
- My [`follow-log-directories`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/follow-log-directories.html) from nosh, which "knows" this kind of log directory and uses a "cursor" (persistently maintained on disc) to reliably track the position in the log directory to continue from even if several rotations happen when the log follower isn't looking.

Other sorts of processing can be done with tools such as:

- Russ Allbery's [`multilog-watch`](http://www.eyrie.org./%7Eeagle/software/multilog-watch/docs.html)
- [`logrange`](http://code.dogmap.org/djbdns/#logrange)
- Paul Kremer's [`multilog-stamptail`](http://pol.spurious.biz/projects/scripting/multilog-stamptail.pod.html)
- My [`export-to-rsyslog`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/export-to-rsyslog.html) from nosh

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). "[Logging](http://jdebp.info/FGA/daemontools-family.html#Logging)". *The daemontools family*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Bryan Cantrill (2013).  *[How a pleasure cruise became an odyssey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vm1GJMp0QN4&feature=youtu.be&t=2442)*.  OmniIT Surge 2013.  YouTube.
- Bryan Cantrill (2012-07-29). *[Behavior of tail -f wrt truncation](http://developer.illumos.narkive.com/nOhCzCuQ/behavior-of-tail-f-wrt-truncation#post1)*  illumos-developers.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294206/5132

Answer (score 7):

@JdeBP already answered what you should probably be doing. But that wasn't the question you made. So to anyone arriving here from Google trying to know how to append/prepend things to a multi-line output, here it is:

First, `^Core*` probably doesn't do what you think it does. It is a regular expression to match lines that start with "Cor" immediately followed by any number of "e"s: "Cor", "Core", "Coreeeee", etc.

Second, `xargs` is a great tool, especially for one-liners and dirty-quick scripts. You can have `xargs` to act on each line of input and issue a command for every one of them with the parameter `-I`. So you can easily do something like this:

```
sensors | grep '^Core*' | xargs -I{} echo "${stamp}: {}" >> temps.log
```

Put `'^Core*'` withing quotes because you don't want unexpected (though highly unlikely) shell expansions there. The `{}` in `-I` tells `xargs` to replace `{}` with each line of input in the arguments of the command it will be executing. You can choose another pattern, of course; I just like to mimic the syntax of `find -exec`. The `${stamp}` assumes you saved the date/time in `stamp`.

You can also raise a subshell, run the `date` command (specifying whatever format you want) in it and have `xargs` use its standard output as part of your arguments to `echo`:

```
sensors | grep '^Core*' | xargs -I{} echo "$(date): {}" >> temps.log
```

Again, what you should *probably* be doing is using a tested and mantained tool for logging. But I'm answering here *how to append/prepend a time stamp to grep output*, not how to properly make your logs.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do:

```
parallel --tagstring `date -Iseconds` 'sensors | grep' ::: ^Core
```

It is short, human readable, and sorts nicely.

Answer (score -1):

```
sensors | grep ^Core* | xargs -d '\n' -I%% sh -c 'echo $(date +%H:%M:%S) $0' %% > temps.log
```