# Circular log in linux

Tags: linux, logs, rsyslog

In FreeBSD there are an utility to support circular log files called [clog](http://software.wheelhouse.org/syslogd/).

This is very interesting for avoid the maintenance of the logs of some services (outside systemd and their journald).

Are there any alternative to do the same in linux and/or with rsyslog?

Comment: Also see [Turning a log file into a sort of circular buffer](https://serverfault.com/questions/133320/turning-a-log-file-into-a-sort-of-circular-buffer), which I think is probably a closer answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are tools to do much the same in *both* FreeBSD *and* Linux, and other operating systems besides.

## Making automatically-rotated strictly size-capped logs

The following tools maintain strictly size-capped, automatically rotated, rotateable-on-demand, log file sets in a directory that one specifies.

- Dan Bernstein's [`multilog`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/multilog.html) from [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html), or Bruce Guenter's [`multilog`](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/multilog.8.html) from [daemontools-encore](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/), or Adam Sampson's `multilog` from [freedt](http://offog.org/code/freedt/)
- Laurent Bercot's [`s6-log`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-log.html) from [s6](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/)
- Gerrit Pape's [`svlogd`](http://smarden.org/runit/svlogd.8.html) from [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/)
- Wayne Marshall's [`tinylog`](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=tinylog.8) from [perp](http://b0llix.net/perp/)
- my [`cyclog`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/cyclog.html) from [nosh](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh.html)

Usage is very simple: Send a to-be-logged process's standard output and standard error through a pipe to their standard input, in the normal way:

```
./thing-to-be-logged 2>&1 | cyclog logs/
```

`cyclog` adds TAI64N timestamps to lines as standard.  For timestamp-free processing when something is already timestamped, use one of the `multilog`s, `s6-log`, or `svlogd`, in each of which timestamp addition is a non-default option.

## Substituting for syslog

What you  point to modifies FreeBSD `syslog` itself, with a patch dating from 2001 that may not apply cleanly nowadays, to have another output file mechanism.

An alternative approach is to simply replace the syslog dæmon completely, alongside configuring more services to simply log to standard error (under service management that pipes standard error to logging services) instead of using syslog in the first place.

For example:  The nosh toolset provides several such substitutes, that split up the job of syslog and generate output suitable for feeding through the standard input of one of the aforementioned logging tools:

- a `klogd` service that runs a simple program named [`klog-read`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/klog-read.html) to read from `/proc/kmsg` and simply write that log stream to its standard error.
- a `local-syslog-read` service that runs a program named [`syslog-read`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/syslog-read.html) to read datagrams from `/dev/log` (`/run/log` on the BSDs) and simply write that log stream to its standard error.
- a `udp-syslog-read` service that runs the aforementioned [`syslog-read`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/syslog-read.html) program to listen on the UDP syslog port and simply write that log stream to its standard error.
- a `local-priv-syslog-read` service that runs the aforementioned [`syslog-read`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/syslog-read.html) program to read datagrams from `/run/logpriv` and simply write that log stream to its standard error.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). "[Logging](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/daemontools-family.html#Logging)". *The daemontools family*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). *[Don't use logrotate or newsyslog in this century.](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/do-not-use-logrotate.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). "[Logging](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/logging.html)".  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294206/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326166/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/340631/5132