# Log redirection happens to rotated log instead of new log getting created

Tags: bash

## Objective

So I have written a script that logs and rotates logs if it reaches certain size. *I wish to capture all the errors and output by other commands also instead of the ones that I deliberately echo into the log.*

The way I have achieved this is by redirecting STDIN and STDOUT to `tee` in a process substitution and have written a small function that makes use of `savelog` to rotate logs.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE="/var/log/ps.log"
exec > >(tee "$LOGFILE") 2>&1

LOGPATH="/var/log"
MAX_LOGFILE_SIZE=5
rotateLog() {
        currentsize=$(du -k $LOGFILE | cut -f1)
        if [ $currentsize -ge $MAX_LOGFILE_SIZE ]; then
                savelog -dn $LOGFILE &>/dev/null
        fi
}

while :; do
    echo "A computer program can easily produce gibberish - especially if it has been provided with garbage beforehand. This program does something a little different. It takes a block of text as input and works out the proportion of characters within the text according to a chosen order. For example, an order of 2 means the program looks at pairs of letters, an order of 3 means triplets of letters and so on. The software can regurgitate random text that is controlled by the proportion of characters. The results can be quite surprising."

    rotateLog

    sleep 5
done
```

## Problem

The problem is that even after the log `ps.log` gets rotated to `ps.log.20180829131658`, all the logs are still written to `ps.log.20180829131658` and following error is thrown:

**du: cannot access '/var/log/ps.log': No such file or directory
./ps.sh: line 12: [: -ge: unary operator expected**

Leading to no further rotation of logs!!!

## Assumption

I was assuming that once `ps.log` gets rotated to `ps.log.20180829131658`, a new log file `ps.log` will get created. But that definitely isn't the case since `exec` is executed only once (*Can anyone please explain what exactly happens here?*) i.e., at the beginning of the script.

## Observation

What also I have observed that a new file descriptor is created for `>(tee "$LOGFILE")` that points to `/var/log/p.log` which gets reassigned to `p.log.20180829131658`! This is what clearly resulting in logs still being written to `p.log.20180829131658`. *Can anyone please explain this behaviour?*

```
root@b537ccc2c1ab:/var/log# ls -lrt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7248 Aug 29 13:16 ps.log

root@b537ccc2c1ab:/var/log# ls -lrt /proc/*/fd
/proc/8979/fd:
total 0
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 29 13:16 3 -> /var/log/ps.log
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 29 13:16 2 -> /dev/pts/17
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 29 13:16 1 -> /dev/pts/17
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Aug 29 13:16 0 -> pipe:[3889791]


root@b537ccc2c1ab:/var/log# ls -lrt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11098 Aug 29 13:17 ps.log.20180829131658

root@b537ccc2c1ab:/var/log# ls -lrt /proc/*/fd
/proc/8979/fd:
total 0
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 29 13:16 3 -> /var/log/ps.log.20180829131658
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 29 13:16 2 -> /dev/pts/17
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 29 13:16 1 -> /dev/pts/17
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Aug 29 13:16 0 -> pipe:[3889791]
```

How can achieve my objective with this logging and log rotation scheme? In particular how can my script write to newer log files besides log rotation while capturing errors and outputs of all other commands in my script alongside?

Comment: Why are you not using `logrotate` or some similar already existing software?

Comment: So I am hosting this script in a docker container which doesn't seem to have logrotate installed by default and I don't want to install yet another utility to keep the container as slim as possible! But nonetheless, I doubt using logrotate will solve this issue, in particular.

Comment: @Kusalananda Apparently we can use `logrotate` with `copytruncate`. Thanks for your suggestion! But I would still prefer not to use `logrotate` for the aforementioned reason!

Comment: You have two choices: 1) install and use `logrotate`. 2) Write your own `logrotate`.  If it was me, I would go with the first option as installing a tried and tested piece of software is quicker and safer than writing my own. Also, in both cases, you are in effect installing a new piece of software. The only difference is who wrote it and how well and safely it's expected to perform.  As a manager, I would also go with the first option, as I wouldn't want to waste my team's time and resources on developing a solution for something that there is already a (free!) solution available for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a process opens a file, you can you all sorts of things to that file such as renaming it, truncating it, even deleting it but the process will still have that file opened. A common mistake is when a logfile has used up all diskspace, one deletes the file in an attempt to free up space. However the process writing to the logfile has it still opened, so the space is not freed. Only when the process closes the file will the blocks allocated to the file be freed. (The workaround here is to truncate the file, i.e. `> logfile`.)

In your case you've renamed the file, but the process writing to it does not know or care about that.

The `logcheck` utility has an option `copytruncate` for such situations: it copies the logfile to the rotated name, and then truncates the original. You can do the same thing:

```
rotateLog() {
    currentsize=$(du -k $LOGFILE | cut -f1)
    if [ $currentsize -ge $MAX_LOGFILE_SIZE ]; then
            ROTATEDLOG=$LOGFILE.$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
            cp -p $LOGFILE $ROTATEDLOG && true > $LOGFILE
    fi
}
```

A better alternative would be to modify the process to understand e.g. the signal SIGHUP to close and reopen the logfile. See the shell `trap` command for handling this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried looking into all the 3 solutions you suggested and got it working by all of them. Much thanks!! I have posted solution as answer based on the 3rd alternative suggested by you. Kindly review it!

Answer (score 0):

Based on an alternative solution suggested by @wurtel, I got it working like so,

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE="/root/logr/simple.log"

function sighuphandler() {
    exec > >(tee "$LOGFILE") 2>&1
}

trap sighuphandler SIGHUP

LOGPATH="/root/logr"
MAX_LOGFILE_SIZE=5
rotateLog() {
    currentsize=$(du -k $LOGFILE | cut -f1)
    if [ $currentsize -ge $MAX_LOGFILE_SIZE ]; then
            savelog -dn $LOGFILE &>/dev/null
            kill -s SIGHUP $$
    fi
}

sighuphandler
while :; do
    echo "[`date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`] [INFO] - A computer program can easily produce gibberish - especially if it has been provided with garbage beforehand. This program does something a little different. It takes a block of text as input and works out the proportion of characters within the text according to a chosen order. For example, an order of 2 means the program looks at pairs of letters, an order of 3 means triplets of letters and so on. The software can regurgitate random text that is controlled by the proportion of characters. The results can be quite surprising."

    ls +

    rotateLog

    sleep 5
done
```

Comment: A better idea is to have the log writer do the rotation, replacing `tee` with one of several programs that have long been available for doing this. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/340631/5132