# How to use bash to create a socket server and allow multiple clients in the same port?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, netcat

I have 4 programs, will be increased in the future, these programs have to connect to the same ip:port to send and receive messages at the same time.

Until now I have the socket opened, I also would like to keep the connection alive between the programs and the server.

```
#!/bin/sh
nc -lvk 88.109.110.161 100 > port100.txt 2>&1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`nc` does not handle multiple connected clients in parallel and is the wrong tool for this job.
There are quite a few right tools for this job, including:

1. Bernstein `tcpserver` (original or djbwares) or Hoffman `tcpserver`:

   ```
   tcpserver -v -R -H -l 0 88.109.110.161 100 sh -c 'exec cat 1>&2' 2>&1 |
   cyclog port100/
   ```
2. my `tcpserver` shim:

   ```
   tcpserver -v 88.109.110.161 100 sh -c 'exec cat 1>&2' 2>&1 |
   cyclog port100/
   ```
3. my UCSPI-TCP tools:

   ```
   tcp-socket-listen 88.109.110.161 100 tcp-socket-accept --verbose sh -c 'exec cat 1>&2' 2>&1 |
   cyclog port100/
   ```
4. Bercot `s6-tcpserver4`:

   ```
   s6-tcpserver4 -v 2 88.109.110.161 100 sh -c 'exec cat 1>&2' 2>&1 |
   cyclog port100/
   ```
5. Bercot s6-networking tools:

   ```
   s6-tcpserver4-socketbinder 88.109.110.161 100 s6-tcpserver4d -v 2 sh -c 'exec cat 1>&2' 2>&1 |
   cyclog port100/
   ```
6. Pape `tcpsvd`:

   ```
   tcpsvd -v 88.109.110.161 100 sh -c 'exec cat 1>&2' 2>&1 |
   cyclog port100/
   ```
7. Sampson `onenetd`:

   ```
   onenetd -v 88.109.110.161 100 sh -c 'exec cat 1>&2' 2>&1 |
   cyclog port100/
   ```

And one can substitute `multilog`, `s6-log`, `svlogd`, or `tinylog` for `cyclog`.

## Further reading

- Protocol:

  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). *[The gen on the UNIX Client-Server Program Interface](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/UCSPI.html)*. Frequently Given Answers.
  - Daniel J. Bernstein (1996). *[UNIX Client-Server Program Interface](http://cr.yp.to/proto/ucspi.txt)*.  cr.yp.to.
- toolsets:

  - Daniel J. Bernstein. *[ucspi-tcp](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp.html)*.  cr.yp.to.
  - Erwin Hoffmann.  [ucspi-tcp6](http://fehcom.de/ipnet/ucspi-tcp6.html).  fehcom.de.
  - [s6-networking](http://skarnet.org/software/s6-networking/index.html).  Laurent Bercot.  skarnet.org.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). *[nosh](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/).*  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). *[djbwares](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/djbwares/).*  Softwares.
  - [ipsvd](http://smarden.org/ipsvd/index.html).  Gerrit Pape.  smarden.org.
  - [onenetd](http://offog.org/code/onenetd/).  Adam Sampson.  offog.org.
- reference manuals:

  - Daniel J. Bernstein. *[The `tcpserver` program](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/tcpserver.html)*.  ucspi-tcp.
  - Erwin Hoffmann.  [`tcpserver`](http://fehcom.de/ipnet/ucspi-tcp6/tcpserver.html).  *ucspi-tcp6*.  fehcom.de.
  - [`s6-tcpserver4`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6-networking/s6-tcpserver4.html).  Laurent Bercot.  *s6-networking*.  skarnet.org.
  - [`tcpsvd`](http://smarden.org/ipsvd/tcpsvd.8.html).  *ipsvd*.  Gerrit Pape.  smarden.org.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). [`tcpserver`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/djbwares/guide/commands/tcpserver.xml).  *djbwares*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). [`tcp-socket-listen`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/tcp-socket-listen.xml).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). [`tcp-socket-accept`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/tcp-socket-accept.xml).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). [`tcpserver`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/tcpserver.xml).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Logging:

  - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/340631/5132
  - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/505854/5132

Comment: One can also consider use a load balancing proxy like `haproxy` in front of the servelets to direct tcp streams based on some filterable information or in a load balance configuration with maxconn = 1

Comment: I will test them and will let you know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

It's a real pity that there's no standard/readily available tool for such basic task, but if you're not on some embedded system and have some scripting language like `perl` or `python` available, you can quickly put something together:

**tcpsrv:**

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use IO::Socket::INET6;
die "usage: $0 host:port { shell_cmd | cmd args ... }\n" unless @ARGV >= 2;
my $h = shift;
my $s=new IO::Socket::INET6(ReusePort=>1, Listen=>6, LocalAddr=>$h)
        or die "IO::Socket::INET($h): $!";
warn "listening on ", $s->sockhost, "/", $s->sockport, "\n";
$SIG{CHLD} = sub { use POSIX qw(WNOHANG); 1 while waitpid(-1, WNOHANG) > 0 };
while(1){
        my $a = $s->accept or do { die "accept: $!" unless $!{EINTR}; next };
        warn "connection from ", $a->peerhost, "/", $a->peerport, "\n";
        die unless defined(my $p = fork);
        close($a), next if $p;
        open STDIN, "<&", $a and open STDOUT, ">&", $a or die "dup: $!";
        close $s and close $a or die "close: $!";
        exec(@ARGV); die "exec @ARGV: $!";
}
```

Usage: `tcpsrv host:port cmd`

This will listen on `host:port`, and anytime a client connects to `host:host`, it will fork & exec `cmd` with its stdin and stdout redirected from/to the connection:

```
tcpsrv :9999 ls .
tcpsrv 127.0.0.1:7000 uptime
tcpsrv [::]:7000 uptime
tcpsrv 88.109.110.161:2000 'cat > port2000.txt'
```

Comment: Never worked with perl, but I will do the attempt, thanks