# systemd-journal: what is the relation of dev-log and syslog?

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I am trying to figure out the relation of the two,

```
/run/systemd/journal/dev-log
/run/systemd/journal/syslog
```

which I could not find enough clear documentation. In certain sense, are they basically the same? Because when I include either one in "unix-dgram()" of syslog-ng, I pretty much get the same output. Is there any difference? Anyway, what is the relation between the two?

Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 7):

It's easy when you know how :)

```
$ systemctl list-sockets 
LISTEN                          UNIT                            ACTIVATES
...
/run/systemd/journal/dev-log    systemd-journald-dev-log.socket systemd-journald.service
/run/systemd/journal/socket     systemd-journald.socket         systemd-journald.service
/run/systemd/journal/stdout     systemd-journald.socket         systemd-journald.service
...

25 sockets listed.
Pass --all to see loaded but inactive sockets, too.
```

ok, I lied about it being so easy.  I don't have a syslog daemon, and that means I don't have syslog.socket activated.  But that's where I found the docs:

```
$ systemctl cat syslog.socket
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/syslog.socket
...
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
Documentation=http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/syslog
...
# The default syslog implementation should make syslog.service a
# symlink to itself, so that this socket activates the right actual
# syslog service.
#
# Examples:
#
# /etc/systemd/system/syslog.service -> /lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service
# /etc/systemd/system/syslog.service -> /lib/systemd/system/syslog-ng.service
#
# Best way to achieve that is by adding this to your unit file
# (i.e. to rsyslog.service or syslog-ng.service):
#
# [Install]
# Alias=syslog.service
#
# See http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/syslog for details.
```

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/syslog/ says:

> Note that it is now the journal that listens on /dev/log, no longer the BSD syslog daemon directly. If your logging daemon wants to get access to all logging data then it should listen on /run/systemd/journal/syslog instead via the syslog.socket unit file that is shipped along with systemd. On a systemd system it is no longer OK to listen on /dev/log directly, and your daemon may not bind to the /run/systemd/journal/syslog socket on its own. If you do that then you will lose logging from STDOUT/STDERR of services (as well as other stuff).

Hence the answer to your question is that you're not supposed to use either of these paths with `unix-dgram()`.  You really need specific systemd support if you want to run as a syslog daemon under it.

For an individual configuration, it sounds like you might get away with binding to `/run/systemd/journal/syslog`.  This is definitely the least evil option, because a) it avoids fighting with journald over who owns `/dev/log`, b) journald will write messages to it from STDOUT/STDERR of services, which are never written to `/dev/log`.  Given that it *appears* to work, I can't see any explicit disadvantages listed in the docs.  The obvious disadvantage is "we do no longer recommend people to order their units after `syslog.target`... early boot messages are lost entirely to your implementation."  There's also a warning that "many services will not be able to log to your syslog implementation", but I think that's incorrect / would only apply if you listened on `/dev/log`.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294206/5132 will help here.