# How to read from the systemd-journald.socket?

Tags: socket, netcat, systemd-journald

To my understanding `systemd-journald` creates a couple `sockets`, where it posts its logging events.

```
# systemctl cat systemd-journald.socket | egrep -v '^ *#'

[Unit]
Description=Journal Socket
Documentation=man:systemd-journald.service(8) man:journald.conf(5)
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=sockets.target

IgnoreOnIsolate=yes

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/systemd/journal/stdout
ListenDatagram=/run/systemd/journal/socket
SocketMode=0666
PassCredentials=yes
PassSecurity=yes
ReceiveBuffer=8M
Service=systemd-journald.service
```

So how can I read these events? I tried:

```
# netcat -U /run/systemd/journal/stdout
# echo $?
0
# netcat -uU /run/systemd/journal/socket
```

`netcat` immediately disconnect from the `stdout` (`exit status` is clean). `netcat` connect to the `socket`, but does not register any events - I can confirm this with the command `journalctl -f -n0` which does show stuff going on, while `socket` output is empty.

Comment: Why do you specifically need to use the socket? Doesn't journalctl -f suffice?

Comment: Just trying to understand what info traverse the sockets and if `syslog-ng` utility shave off anything when it reads from them.

Comment: You have completely the wrong end of the stick.  These are not the sockets that syslog programs read from.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294206/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362681/ for starters.  This question has a quite erroneous premise, so is not really answerable.

Comment: @JdeBP Can you elaborate more? In your own post you state `'/run/systemd/journal/syslog' it writes journal data there`. I just tried `netcat -uU /run/systemd/journal/syslog` which yielded no results either. FYI I have `Alias=syslog.service` in my `syslog-ng.service` which to my understanding activates `/run/systemd/journal/syslog`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you may use [`systemd-journal-remote`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-journal-remote.8.html):

> `systemd-journal-remote` is a command to receive serialized journal
> events and store them to journal files. Input streams are in the
> [Journal Export Format](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/export), i.e. like the output from `journalctl output=export`. For transport over the network, this serialized
> stream is usually carried over an HTTPS connection.