# Prevent syslogs from being logged under journalctl

Tags: systemd, rsyslog, systemd-journald, journaling, journalctl

I have a simple Python snippet managed by a `systemd` service which logs to the `rsysogd` daemon where I've defined a configuration file to put it to a syslog server with a format I've defined. This is working fine so far.

In the code below, I'm passing the argument as the string I want to log on the server. I'm using this code below as a module and using it for logging alone, the actual script uses this for logging purposes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import syslog
import sys

syslog.openlog(facility=syslog.LOG_LOCAL0)
syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_INFO, sys.argv[1])
```

Since the application is managed by `systemd` it is making a copy of the syslog available when seen from the `journalctl -xe` and the `journalctl -u <my-service>` which I do not wish to happen because I've other critical information I'm logging in journal logs.

The service definition is

```
[Unit]
Description=Computes device foobar availability status

[Service]
Type=simple

EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/db_EndPoint
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /opt/foobar/foobar.py
WatchdogSec=60
RestartSec=10
Restart=always
LimitNOFILE=4096

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

and in the `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` file, I've not enabled *any* of the options to be available. I looked up this [journald.conf](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html) documentation to use `ForwardToSyslog=no` and did a restart of `journald` service as

```
systemctl restart systemd-journald
```

and also restarted my service unit, but I see the logs out to the syslog server *and* also to the journal logs. What option I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a simple Python snippet managed by a systemd service which logs to the rsys[l]ogd daemon […]

No you haven't.

What you have is a service that logs to the systemd journal.  The server listening on the well-known `/dev/log` socket that your Python program is talking to is not `rsyslogd`.  It is `systemd-journald`.  `rsyslogd` is *attached to the other side* of `systemd-journald`, and your Python program is not talking to it.

From this, it should be apparent that the only way to not send stuff via `systemd-journald` is to use some *other* route to `rsyslogd`, *not* the well known socket that your Python library uses by default.  That all depends from how you have configured `rsyslogd`.

- It is possible that you have turned on a UDP server with the `imudp` module, in which case you could tell your Python program to use that by using a different Python library that speaks to such a UDP server.  (The Python syslog library is hardwired to use the well-known local socket.)
- Or (and better, given that you have to be careful about not opening a UDP service to the world outwith your machine) you could have given `rsyslogd` a second, not well known, `AF_LOCAL` socket to listen to by configuring this in the `imuxsock` module's configuration.  Again, you'll have to tell your Python program to use that and use a different Python library.

What exactly you do in your Python program is beyond the scope of this answer.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294206/5132

Comment: Yes! I realize the mistakes I've made. Well but do you have a working example (for `some other route` you meant in the answe) can I write to `rsyslogd` bypassing `systemd-journald`