# runsv not redirecting standard error output, why?

Tags: logs, init, runit

According to the [`runsv` man page](http://smarden.org/runit/runsv.8.html):

> If the directory service/log exists, runsv creates  a  pipe,  redirects
>   service/run's   and  service/finish's  standard  output  to  the  pipe,
>   switches to the directory service/log  and  starts  ./run  script.  The
>   standard input of the log service is redirected to read from the pipe.

Obviously, `runsv` only redirects service's standard output, but not standard
error output, to svlogd standard input. My question is: why? Of course I want
to log my unit's standard error output; why do I have to pay extra attention
to adding `exec 2>&1` to the beginning of each unit file?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't.

`runsv` takes this behaviour from [`svscan`](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools/svscan.html) in the original Bernstein daemontools, which did the same.  Almost everyone else has copied it.  Bruce Guenter's [`svscan`](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/svscan.8.html) from daemontools-encore, Laurent Bercot's [`s6-svscan`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-svscan.html) from s6, and Wayne Marshall's [`perpd`](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=perpd.8) from perp all do likewise.

Even Adam Sampson's `svscan` from [freedt](http://offog.org/code/freedt/) connects only standard output, despite calling the file descriptor `err` in the code. ☺

Noticing how extensively `exec 2>&1` and `fdmove -c 2 1` had become the norm, and observing that some programming languages explicitly define a *standard log* stream that ends up being file descriptor 2 (e.g. `std::clog` in C++), I made [`service-manager`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/service-manager.html) in the nosh toolset connect both standard output *and* standard error to the pipe when plumbing services together.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). [*A side-by-side look at run scripts and service units.*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/run-scripts-and-service-units-side-by-side.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). "[Logging](http://jdebp.eu/FGA/daemontools-family.html#Logging)". *The daemontools family*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294206/5132

Comment: Thanks for answer! Do you have any explanation why daemontools' original behaviour was to only redirect `stdout` but not `stderr`? Because that's what I'm interested in in the first place.