# How does journald know the PID of a process that produces log data?

Tags: systemd-journald, ipc

When I look at `journalctl`, it tells me the PID and the program name(or service name?) of a log entry.

Then I wondered, logs are created by other processes, how do `systemd-journald` know the PID of these processes when processes may only write raw strings to the unix domain socket which `systemd-journald` is listenning. Also, do `sytemd-journald` always use the same technique to detect the PID of a piece of log data even when processes are producing log using functions like `sd_journal_sendv()`?

Is there any documentation I should read about this?

I read [JdeBP's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205883/understand-logging-in-linux) and know `systemd-journald` listen on an Unix Domian Socket, but even if can know the peer socket address who send the log message, how does it know the PID? What if that sending socket is opened by many non-parent-children processes?

Comment: See: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journald.service.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It receives the pid via the `SCM_CREDENTIALS` ancillary data on the unix socket with `recvmsg()`, see `unix(7)`. The credentials don't have to be sent explicitly.

Example:

```
$ cc -Wall scm_cred.c -o scm_cred
$ ./scm_cred
scm_cred: received from 10114: pid=10114 uid=2000 gid=2000
```

Processes with `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` data can send whatever pid they want via `SCM_CREDENTIALS`; in the case of `systemd-journald`, this means they can fake entries as if logged by another process:

```
# cc -Wall fake.c -o fake
# setcap CAP_SYS_ADMIN+ep fake

$ ./fake `pgrep -f /usr/sbin/sshd`

# journalctl --no-pager -n 1
...
Dec 29 11:04:57 debin sshd[419]: fake log message from 14202
# rm fake
# lsb_release -d
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.6 (stretch)
```

`systemd-journald` handles datagrams and credentials sent via ancillary data is in the [`server_process_datagram()`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/7b3b9822176bf9d69dc761e2c3bc89059918caae/src/journal/journald-server.c#L1284) function from `journald-server.c`. Both the `syslog(3)` standard function from `libc` and `sd_journal_sendv()` from `libsystemd` will send their data via a `SOCK_DGRAM` socket by default, and `getsockopt(SO_PEERCRED)` does not work on datagram (connectionless) sockets. Neither `systemd-journald` nor `rsyslogd` accept `SOCK_STREAM` connections on `/dev/log`.

**scm_cred.c**

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE     1
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <err.h>

int main(void){
        int fd[2]; pid_t pid;
        if(socketpair(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_DGRAM, 0, fd)) err(1, "socketpair");
        if((pid = fork()) == -1) err(1, "fork");
        if(pid){ /* parent */
                int on = 1;
                union {
                        struct cmsghdr h;
                        char data[CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(struct ucred))];
                } buf;
                struct msghdr m = {0};
                struct ucred *uc = (struct ucred*)CMSG_DATA(&buf.h);
                m.msg_control = &buf;
                m.msg_controllen = sizeof buf;
                if(setsockopt(fd[0], SOL_SOCKET, SO_PASSCRED, &on, sizeof on))
                        err(1, "setsockopt");
                if(recvmsg(fd[0], &m, 0) == -1) err(1, "recvmsg");
                warnx("received from %d: pid=%d uid=%d gid=%d", pid,
                        uc->pid, uc->uid, uc->gid);
        }else   /* child */
                write(fd[1], 0, 0);
        return 0;
}
```

**fake.c**

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE     1
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <err.h>

int main(int ac, char **av){
        union {
                struct cmsghdr h;
                char data[CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(struct ucred))];
        } cm;
        int fd; char buf[256];
        struct ucred *uc = (struct ucred*)CMSG_DATA(&cm.h);
        struct msghdr m = {0};
        struct sockaddr_un ua = {AF_UNIX, "/dev/log"};
        struct iovec iov = {buf};
        if((fd = socket(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) err(1, "socket");
        if(connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&ua, SUN_LEN(&ua))) err(1, "connect");
        m.msg_control = &cm;
        m.msg_controllen = cm.h.cmsg_len = CMSG_LEN(sizeof(struct ucred));
        cm.h.cmsg_level = SOL_SOCKET;
        cm.h.cmsg_type = SCM_CREDENTIALS;
        uc->pid = ac > 1 ? atoi(av[1]) : getpid();
        uc->uid = ac > 2 ? atoi(av[2]) : geteuid();
        uc->gid = ac > 3 ? atoi(av[3]) : getegid();
        iov.iov_len = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "<13>%s from %d",
                ac > 4 ? av[4] : "fake log message", getpid());
        if(iov.iov_len >= sizeof buf) errx(1, "message too long");
        m.msg_iov = &iov;
        m.msg_iovlen = 1;
        if(sendmsg(fd, &m, 0) == -1) err(1, "sendmsg");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see. So get the sender's info doesn't need the sender process to send it initiatively. But what if the sender process has CAP_SYS_ADMIN and `sendmsg()` a PID different from its own? Will `systemd-journald` get tricked by this behaviour?

Comment: no, the kernel checks the credentials. that's mentioned in the unix(7) manpage under SCM_CREDENTIALS.

Comment: Yeah, but it mentioned `The sender must specify its own process ID (unless it has the capability CAP_SYS_ADMIN)`. That's why I mention the CAP_SYS_ADMIN, am I misunderstanding anything?

Comment: Yes, a process with `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` can send a pid different from its own. (Haven't tested it, though)

Comment: This has apparently changed over recent years. If a process forks children and shares stdout/stderr with them, on systemd 219, the `_PID` is always the parent pid on the journal regardless of which process wrote to stdout. On the other hand, as of systemd 247 the `_PID` in the journal correctly matches the pid of the originating child.

Comment: @istepaniuk No, this answer predates that change, and is about a different thing. This is about old-style daemons which are using `syslog(3)` (or systemd's `sd_journal_sendv()`) to log messages in a "stateless" manner (by just sending them to a *datagram* unix-domain socket), not about processes managed (in a "stateful" manner) by systemd, which are "logging" by just writing to their stdout and stderr (redirected to a *stream* socket by systemd). It's great that they finally fixed that bug, nonetheless ;-)

Comment: @istepaniuk also read my comments to JdeBP's answer, where I tried (in vain!) to explain the difference between the `SO_PEERCRED` and `SO_PASSCRED` mechanisms. There is a lot of confusion around them, apparently shared by the systemd people, too. `SO_PEERCRED` is especially broken, but neither of them can be reliaby used to determine that you're getting the data from the right user or process.

Comment: @mosvy Thanks for clarifying. I was puzzled about this so I created this other question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/630145/how-can-i-have-the-pids-in-the-systemd-journal-for-proecesses-that-share-the-sta/630154#630154, specifically about what changed between systemd versions in this other aspect (identifying the PID of the stdout stream)

Answer (score 2):

## The kernel tells it.

The EUID, EGID, and PID of the original client process that connected the `AF_LOCAL` stream socket at `/run/systemd/journal/stdout` is available from the kernel via the `SO_PEERCRED` socket option, [which it uses](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/7b3b9822176bf9d69dc761e2c3bc89059918caae/src/journal/journald-stream.c#L560).  UCSPI-UNIX tools obtain this same information via the same system call.

Child service processes of course inherit their standard I/O file descriptors already opened (unless the parent service process changes this, of course), and so to `systemd-journald` all log output has the credentials of the original parent process.

Log output generated via the `AF_LOCAL` socket at `/run/systemd/journal/socket` that speaks the idiosyncratic `systemd-journald` protocol is coming over a datagram socket, rather than a stream one.  This socket [is flagged using the `SO_PASSCRED` socket option](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/7b3b9822176bf9d69dc761e2c3bc89059918caae/src/journal/journald-native.c#L461) so that the kernel records the same information in each datagram sent, which [is pulled out of each datagram](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/5cfa2c3dc09ffed16e3ad249e893911e372d3ed0/src/journal/journald-server.c#L1284) by `systemd-journald`.

## Further reading

- [`getsockopt()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockopt.2.html). *Linux Programmers' Manual*. 2017-09-15.
- [`socket`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html). *Linux Programmers' Manual*. 2018-02-02.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2017). [`local-stream-socket-accept`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/local-stream-socket-accept.html). *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). "[Environment variables](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/UCSPI.html#Variables)".  *The gen on the UNIX Client-Server Program Interface*. Frequently Given Answers.

Comment: no, it doesn't get it via `SO_PEERCRED`, but via ancillary data with `recvmsg`. I've `strace`'d `systemd-journald`.

Comment: … and you haven't read what you are commenting on, or my previous answer referred to in the question, or indeed all of what the question asks.

Comment: Because the rude dress-down may give the wrong impressions wrt the **accuracy** of this answer, I want to make it clear: **this answer is wrong**. I'll try to explain why. **1.** Portable apps which are using `syslog()` do **not** connect to the stream socket from `/run/systemd/journal/stdout`; they simply send their data from an **unconnected**, **datagram** to `/dev/log`. Since `SO_PEERCRED` is getting the creds of the process that **connected** to a socket, and does not work with connectionless sockets, it cannot be and is **not** used to get the pid of the process that called `syslog()`.

Comment: **2.** unless overrided by a privileged process, the creds that `systemd` gets via `recvmsg` as described in my [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/491421/308316) will be those of the process that called `send()` by way of `syslog()`, not of the parent process that created the socket or called `connect()` on it. The second paragraph is particularly misleading, because even `SO_PEERCRED` on a connection-based socket will not return the creds of the process that created the socket file descriptor, but of the process that `connect()`ed it.

Comment: **3.** The `SO_PASSCRED` option should be set on the socket on which the creds are to be received, not on the socket on which they're sent, and it does **not** cause the kernel to stick the same info in each datagram sent in the way it's described in the 3rd paragraph.

Comment: What you are actually making clear is that _you don't read_. You didn't read the question talking about logs going to journald from child processes, or my answer explaining how standard output and error go to journald through the _very_ mechanism that you've erroneously claimed is not used at the client end. You didn't read _this_ answer which clearly draws a distinction between that, where `SO_PEERCRED` most definitely _is_ used despite your erroneous claims to the contrary, and others. You didn't even read where this answer _showed you_ exactly where the systemd code is doing what I state.

Comment: I completely stand by the accuracy of the description from my answer and comments, that I've checked and re-checked. `systemd-journald` is only using `SO_PEERCRED` for a stream socket opened by `sd_journal_stream_fd()` (`/run/systemd/journal/stdout`) which is **absolutely not used** by the standard `syslog(3)` or the `sd_journal_send*` and `sd_journal_print*` functions, which are all using **datagram** sockets, on which `SO_PEERCRED` **does not work**.

Comment: I'm not aware of any program that's using that `sd_journal_stream_fd` stream log facility and I don't think that a syslog program that keeps states of clients is a good idea in the 1st place, but that's a completely different matter, not related to this question. As to 'not reading', that simply amounts to bullying; of course I've read everything, it's simply that I prefer to base my answers on **facts**, rather than do exegesis of other people's answers and second guess what has misled them into believing things that are not true.