# How can I have the PIDs in the systemd journal for proecesses that share the standard output file descriptor?

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, fork

When a process `fork()`s children *without* closing and reopening standard IO, all children share the same IO file descriptors.

By default, running such forking process in a systemd unit will result in any standard output being written to the journal, as expected.

On systemd 241 (Debian buster, Linux 4.19) these journal entries have a `_PID` field matching the PID **of the parent** process (the one that systemd started), no matter what process actually wrote to stdout (or stderr).

However... on systemd 247 (Debian bullseye, Linux 5.9) the journal `_PID` entry correctly matches the PID of **the process who actually wrote** to the shared stdout file descriptor. I am guessing it does this by reading some magic flags on the socket receive logic, which is awesome.

I have read through [the systemd changelog](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/NEWS) and I can't understand at what point this changed and how, or if something is just configured differently.

**Is there a way to have matching _PID tags on the journal for the systemd and Linux kernel shipped with buster?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> at what point this changed and how

at v243-534-[g09d0b46ab6](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/09d0b46ab61bebafe5bdc1be95e): "journal: refresh cached credentials of stdout streams"

> Is there a way to have matching `_PID` tags on the journal for the systemd and Linux kernel shipped with buster?

you can try applying just that change, and rebuilding.