# Writing to /dev/kmsg randomly shows up in /proc/kmsg and always in dmesg?

Tags: linux-kernel, rsyslog, dmesg

When writing a message to `/dev/kmsg` while tailing `/proc/kmsg` the messages show up very randomly, in never shows up in `/var/log/kern.log`.

However, `dmesg` gets all the messages correctly.

**Example**

```
# Terminal 1
sudo tail -f /proc/kmsg

# Terminal 2 
tail -f /var/log/kern.log

# Terminal 3
sudo sh -c 'echo "<1> Kernel log message" > /dev/kmsg'
sudo sh -c 'echo "<1> Kernel log message" > /dev/kmsg'
sudo sh -c 'echo "<1> Kernel log message" > /dev/kmsg'
sudo sh -c 'echo "<1> Kernel log message" > /dev/kmsg'
```

Results:

```
# Terminal 1
# The message is shown at irregular intervals without a clear pattern
sudo tail -f /proc/kmsg
    <9>[37102.185491]  Kernel log message

# Terminal 2 
# No message is ever shown
tail -f /var/log/kern.log

# Terminal 4
# Everything is always here
dmesg
    [37101.556366]  Kernel log message
    [37102.185491]  Kernel log message
    [37103.042422]  Kernel log message
```

When plugging in an USB stick, the data gets randomly split between output from `/proc/kmsg` and `/var/log/kern.log`. `dmesg` again show all the messages.

- What is `dmesg` doing differently from other approaches?
- Why is it possible to just break rsyslog's kernel logging by having another process listen to `/dev/kmsg`. Why aren't my attempts blocked with `device or resource busy`?
- Why doesn't rsyslog ever log the messages sent to `/dev/kmsg` even though they do occasionally reach `proc/kmsg`?

Comment: Don't understand why you mention `/var/log/kern.log`, it's not touched by the kernel, unlike the other two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/proc/kmsg` is not shareable amongst log readers, and if there are multiple readers only one of them will receive any given log message.  `/dev/kmsg` is shareable amongst multiple log readers, providing the whole log stream (pace underruns by slow readers) to each reader.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294206/5132

Comment: Accepting the answer, basic question solved. If you have the knowledge of the historical context of why both exist and which serves which use case, that would be a great expansion of the answer.