# What is the difference between /proc/kmsg and /dev/kmsg?

Tags: kernel, logs

I am learning about `journald` and `rsyslog` and while reading I saw that `rsyslog` reads from `/dev/kmsg` and that `journald` can read from both `/dev/kmsg` and `/proc/ksmg`.

I know these are both kernel logs, but what is the difference between `/proc/kmsg` and `/dev/kmsg`? Why is one appear to be a process and another appear to be a device?

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503059/5132 .

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`/proc/kmsg` provides a root-only, read-only, *consuming* view of the kernel log buffer. It’s equivalent to calling [`syslog(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syslog.2.html) with the `SYSLOG_ACTION_READ` action. As mentioned in [the `proc` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html),

> A process must have superuser privileges to read this file, and only one process should read this
>                 file.  This file should not be read if a syslog process is
>                 running which uses the [`syslog(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syslog.2.html) system call facility to log
>                 kernel messages.

`/dev/kmsg` provides access to the same kernel log buffer, but in an easier-to-use fashion. Reads are tracked per open, so multiple processes can read in parallel, and entries aren’t removed from the buffer as they are read. `/dev/kmsg` also provides *write* access to the log buffer, so it can be used to add entries to the log buffer. See [the `/dev/kmsg` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/dev-kmsg) for details.

As for why both are present, and why one is in `/proc` (albeit not process-related) and one in `dev`, `/proc/kmsg` is an old convenience “export” of kernel internals, and `/dev/kmsg` is [a more recent addition](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=e11fea92e13fb91c50bacca799a6131c81929986), designed as a usable interface to the log buffer.