# rsyslogd sometimes doesn't write the initial bits of dmesg to /var/log/syslog

Tags: kernel, syslog, rsyslog, dmesg, rsyslogd

I have a Linux machine running Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS that uses `rsyslogd`. My understanding of `rsyslogd` is that it rotates the content from the kernel ring buffer (ie, `dmesg`) to an on-disk file (ie, `/var/log/syslog`).

So nominally in `/var/log/syslog`, I expect see a "start" message from `rsyslogd` followed by kernel messages that I can later retrieve in `dmesg`. Notice how the first kernel message starts at a relative 0.0000s time.

```
$ cat /var/log/syslog
... 
rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="4970" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
...
kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
```

Sometimes, when I look at `/var/log/syslog`, I'd notice that the first kernel message starts as late as 40+ seconds:

```
$ cat /var/log/syslog
... 
rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="4970" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
...
kernel: [   45.829155] IRQ6 no longer affine to CPU4
```

If I then immediately look at `dmesg`, I'd find the missing "Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0" message.

```
$ dmesg | head -n1
kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
```

All this makes me think that for *some* reason, `rsyslogd` occasionally encounters a race condition in which it doesn't log the first bits of kernel messages. But I have no idea how to go about troubleshooting this. I would love to get some pointers on how to get to the bottom of this problem.

Comment: [This is a good explanation rsyslog and "kernel printk buffer"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585922/21203),  Indeed, most likely another app is reading `/proc/kmsg` before `rsyslog` does.  This [Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12247/21203) has some Answers with file monitoring ideas.  In this case, the read of `/proc/kmsg` happens early in the boot process.  1. figure out a "read access monitor" recipe 2. Hack one of the first running service files to also launch your "read access monitor" recipe. 3. Post your recipe and the culprit process in an Answer here 

Comment: Just so I understand, `/proc/kmsg` can only be read by one caller at a time. And you're suspecting that two callers may be accessing it simultaneously (ie, rsyslogd and some other process)? If so, if I update rsyslogd to read from `/dev/kmsg` (which supports parallel reads), I should expect the problem to go away?

Comment: "_`/proc/kmsg` can only be read by one caller at a time._". No. The contents of `/proc/kmsg` can only be read _once_. That read data within `/proc/kmsg` is then immediately deleted by the kernel.  So whichever process reads `/proc/kmsg` first during bootup is the one that sees the kernel log messages it contains.
Something else to try: If your rsyslog process reads from `/proc/kmsg` then try changing that to `/dev/kmsg` as recommended in the linked Answer. `/dev/kmsg` does not have "read once" behavior.

Comment: I figured it out, much credits to you! Going to leave breadcrumbs by answering my own question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure this out with the help of `auditd`, which tracks whenever a file of interest has been accessed. Long story short, I had `rsyslog` and `logd` both enabled, and they both want to read `/proc/kmsg`. However, as @JamesThomasMoon pointed out, `/proc/kmsg` is cleared after someone reads it. So depending on whether `rsyslogd` or `logd` gets to `/proc/kmsg`, my system sometimes has missing syslog.

Here's roughly the steps I took to figure this out...

1. Install `auditd` using `apt-get`, as usual.
2. Add an `auditd` rule called `proc_kmsg` that says *"whenever someone reads `/proc/kmsg`, note it down"*.

```
$ cat /etc/audit/rules.d/foobar.rule
-w /proc/kmsg     -p r    -k proc_kmsg
```

3. Load the added rules so it takes effect.

```
$ augenrules --load
```

4. Reboot the system.
5. Read the `auditd` logs to see what tried to access `/proc/kmsg`.

```
$ ausearch -k proc_kmsg --interpret
```

6. In my case, I noticed a line that indicates `/usr/sbin/rsyslogd` attempted to read `/proc/kmsg`, and there's another line that indicates `/sbin/logd` is also trying to read `/proc/kmsg`. It was never my intention to enable both `rsyslogd` and `logd`, so I disabled `logd` accordingly and voila.

```
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(05/30/23 18:10:50.266:28) : proctitle=/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
```

and

```
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(05/30/23 18:10:50.846:32) : proctitle=/sbin/logd
```