# How to execute a program from terminal redirecting stdout and stderr to systemd's journal?

Tags: systemd, gnome

Is there an easy way to run a command from the terminal the same way it is run from GNOME's Alt + F2, redirecting stdout and stderr to systemd's journal?

I've tried gmrun (does not redirect outputs), gtk-launch (works only for .desktop files in /usr/share/applications).

Is there a GNOME or a systemd command to do this?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205883/understand-logging-in-linux/294206#294206 then you can figure out how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`systemd-run --user ...`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run.html)

Unfortunately, the most user-friendly mode is not used by default.

> By default, services created with `systemd-run` default to the `simple` type [...] Consider using the `exec` service type (i.e. `--property=Type=exec`) to ensure that `systemd-run` returns successfully only if the specified command line has been successfully started.

This more useful setting was added later.  Personally, I do not think I would remember this detail.  So I would prefer to use a short wrapper script.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you should use the `logger(1)` utility, which works no matter if your system is using `systemd` or `rsyslogd`.

```
your_prog 2>&1 | logger -t your_prog
```

On systems with systemd, there's also `systemd-cat` which is specifically using systemd's "streaming" logging api (`sd_journal_stream_fd(3)`, `/run/systemd/journal/stdout`) instead of the standard `syslog(3)`:

```
your_prog 2>&1 | systemd-cat -t your_prog

systemd-cat -t your_prog your_prog
```

To save another search: If you want to pipe only the stderr but not the stdout, you can use

```
log_stderr(){ { "$@" 2>&1 >&3 3>&- | logger -t "$1"; } 3>&1; }
log_stderr your_prog
```