# Difference between /dev/log vs /dev/kmsg?

Tags: linux, kernel, logs

what is the actual use of /dev/log, while googling it I understand it is used for logging from userspace to Syslog. I thought /dev/kmsg is used for that role. Am I missing anything?

Note:

```
test@test:~$ cat /dev/log
cat: /dev/log: No such device or address
```

Answer (score 1):

It's described in `man syslogd`:

> ```
>    /dev/log
>           The Unix domain socket to from where local syslog messages are read.
> ```

You can see yourself that it's used by `syslogd` using `logger` command for example:

```
$ strace -f logger a 2>&1 | grep  /dev/log
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = 0
```

Or `lsof` (if available):

```
$ sudo lsof /dev/log
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /home/ja/.cache/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
syslogd 860 root    0u  unix 0x0000000003d863fa      0t0 18404 /dev/log type=DGRAM
```

Notice that there are multiple implementations of `syslogd` on various
systems - Slackware for example comes with sysklogd but various
embedded platforms come with their own implementation such as Busybox.

I believe you might also confuse `syslog(2)` and `syslog(3)`:

```
$ man -k syslog | grep '^syslog '
syslog (2)           - read and/or clear kernel message ring buffer; set console_loglevel
syslog (3)           - send messages to the system logger
```

`syslog(2)` is a syscall (also listed in `man syscalls`) used by
`dmesg` through libc `klogctl` API to *read and/or clear kernel
message* ring buffer while `syslog(3)` is used to *send* messages to
syslogd.  These 2 functions are named the same but they are used for
completely different purposes and work differently internally.

Answer (score 1):

- `/dev/log` is (or is a symbolic link to) an `AF_LOCAL` datagram socket, which applications are expected to *send* datagrams *to*, not *read* stream data *from* with `cat`.  It is a convention of C libraries, and their library functions such as the `syslog()` function, and not a part of Linux itself.  It's readers will be a dæmon such as `syslog-read`, one of the syslog variants, or `systemd-journald`.
- `/dev/kmsg` is a stream device that *is* a part of Linux, presenting the contents of Linux's circular message buffer, which applications are expected to *read from* in order to obtain kernel log data; and not really write to in normal circumstances.  The normal readers are the `dmesg` program and a dæmon such as `klog-read`, `klogd`, one of the syslog variants, or `systemd-journald`.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294206/5132
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). "[Handling old log mechanisms](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/old-log-services.html)".  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.