# How can journald be disabled?

Tags: systemd, rsyslog, systemd-journald

I've recently learned that `journalctl` is occupying a big chunk of my 16GB SD card (Raspberry Pi):

```bash
$ journalctl --disk-usage
Archived and active journals take up 312.1M in the file system.
```

I don't feel that `journalctl` and `journald` are [pulling their weight](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+your+weight) in my use case for this machine.
It's an old-ish RPi, and `rsyslog` is also running. I estimate my need for and use of `journalctl` is maybe [*"once in a blue moon"*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/once+in+a+blue+moon). Consequently, I decided I would disable `journald` - which "feeds" `journalctl`. I assumed this would be straightforward, using `systemctl` to `stop`, or perhaps just `disable`ing the `systemd-journald.service` so that it would not start on the next boot.

Before pulling the plug, I decided to do somee research. Instead of finding thousands of references that offered "how-to" advice, there were remarkably few results addressing my specific search term: *"how to disable journald"*. Instead, the results mostly offered advice on reducing `journald`'s *resource consumption*. I did find a couple of references that gave me pause:

An old thread in the ArchLinux forum suggested it was not possible to disable `journald` without [*repercussions*](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=149884); i.e. `"Masking systemd-journald causes all kinds of dependency failures and drops you at an emergency prompt."` But this post is now 10 years old...

The [systemd-journald.service manual](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/systemd/systemd-journald.service.8.en.html) says, `"stopping it [systemd-journald.service] is not recommended."`. The documentation proceeds from there to discuss *namespaces*?

I've learned that the usual command to prevent `systemd` units from starting has no effect; i.e. it starts normally:

```
$ sudo systemctl disable systemd-journald.service
$ sudo reboot 

# ... and after boot & login:

$ systemctl status systemd-journald.service
● systemd-journald.service - Journal Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-06-03 07:30:29 UTC; 1min 59s ago
TriggeredBy: ● systemd-journald-audit.socket
             ● systemd-journald.socket
             ● systemd-journald-dev-log.socket
       Docs: man:systemd-journald.service(8)
             man:journald.conf(5)
   Main PID: 134 (systemd-journal)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 1598)
        CPU: 820ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-journald.service
             └─134 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald

...
$
```

##### How can `journald` be disabled? ... or can it be disabled?

If not, why would the `systemd` developers force this on users? (OK, yeah - asking for an opinion, so forget that part of the question.)

Comment: Please try disabling all the TriggeredBy's as well (systemd-journald-audit.socket
             systemd-journald.socket
             systemd-journald-dev-log.socket). This should work. I'm not going to test this on my working PC ;-)

Comment: I'd like to configure a system (an RPi Zero) to be "read only" and minimize all CPU activity that's not necessary for what I'm doing. I'm here because I was thinking disabling system services, like logging, might be a good approach... at a minimum, an interesting exercise. Sounds like I might need to seek an embedded distro.

Comment: @Seamus See [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/747141/111943).  I just spent half a day ripping systemd's benighted journaling from a bunch of systems because it couldn't handle the load of a system running with debug logs set.  Loads that caused systemd to use 3+ entire CPUs while losing messages are now handled by a single rsyslogd process that takes about 17% of a single CPU.  And it doesn't lose any log messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason not to want to eliminate `journald` when you are using `rsyslogd` is that `rsyslogd` can get it's information *from* journald, and they play very well together this way.

That is sort of contra some of the Q&A's linked in comments here.  Some observations about this on a current linux system (checked this on Fedora and Debian) which is configured to have journald use only volatile (in memory) storage, with `rsyslog` writing actual log files:

- `/var/run/log` is a directory with one subdirectory, `journal`.  This contains files written to by `systemd-journald` and **read by** `rsyslogd`.
  Note this directory is on a `tmpfs` partition, hence it counts as in memory volatile storage.
- `/dev/log` is a symlink to `/run/systemd/journal/dev-log`.

The `/etc/rsyslog.conf` on these systems includes this (which is not the stock `rsyslog.conf`):

```
# Input
module (
        load="imjournal"
        ...
)
```

Fedora and Debian differ in the stock config here; the former does use `imjournal` as well as `imuxsock` (userspace socket).<sup>1</sup> Debian uses `imuxsock` and `imklog` (kernel log), presumably because without `imjournal` it needs to listen to the kernel itself.  I also presume this is a bit anachronistic.

Part of my point here is that completely ripping out journald may not be impossible but it is a bad idea.  It is a core component of contemporary systemd based systems. It's deficit is that it potentially uses much more disk space than rsyslog, but this is easy to configure out by using `Storage=volatile` and (eg) `RuntimeMaxUse=64M` in `/etc/systemd/journald`,

Having rsyslogd fed from journald is a back-end/front-end relationship; rsyslog is great because it provides plain text logging as well as much more fine grained control over what gets logged where and how, while journald provides better integration with system services.

---

1. The rsyslog recommendation is to use `imuxsock` as `imuxjournal` is less efficient and may suffer from other issues; see also Andrew Henle's answer about this and comments below.

Comment: A well-reasoned argument - thank you. I *feel* like this is the correct answer, and the answer I expected as there's virtually nothing in the way of *how-to-recipes* explaining how `journald` might be removed or disabled. And since this is a comment, I'll express an opinion in closing: `journald` is to Linux what `Siri` is to Apple: You might not like it, but you're "forced" (more or less) to accept something you revile in order to get something you want or need.

Comment: Journald could certainly use some work on that front end part for contexts where it is the only logger (which it probably is now on most linux systems).  It's only features are `--unit` to get service specific stuff, and of course it's colourful.  BTW, I added a footnote that I realized might be important if you are putting this information into practice.

Comment: my servers struggle with postfix on Debian stable with systemd: some messages that postfix logs correctly into journald do not get forwarded to the log-server via rsyslogd.  with journalctl -feu "postfix*" they can be observed on the postfix-system while on log-server, tail -f /var/log/mail.info only provides some.  I seems to me that on the postfix-server either rsyslogd or journald consider the sequences of log-messages to exhaust the burst-limits.  Tests with either or both imuxsock as well as imjournal have not helped. Any hints?

Comment: @luke Have you tried [tinkering with the rate limit](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imjournal.html#ratelimit-interval)?  Imuxsock has a similar feature: https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imuxsock.html#input-rate-limiting  Although it is noted there that "the journal tends to drop messages when it becomes busy instead of forwarding them to the system log socket".  I'd presume that doesn't apply to the journal, although maybe that is optimistic.

Comment: *they play very well together this way* Not according to the [`rsyslog` documentation](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imjournal.html): "Note that this module reads the journal database, what is considered a relatively performance-intense operation. As such, the performance of a configuration utilizing this module may be notably slower than when using imuxsock." and then (bolding is original to rsyslog): "**Warning**: Some versions of systemd journal have problems with database corruption,

Comment: (continued) ...which leads to the journal to return the same data endlessly in a tight loop. This results in massive message duplication inside rsyslog probably resulting in a denial-of-service when the system resources get exhausted. This can be somewhat mitigated by using proper rate-limiters, but even then there are spikes of old data which are endlessly repeated. By default, ratelimiting is activated and permits to process 20,000 messages within 10 minutes, what should be well enough for most use cases. If insufficient, use the parameters described below to adjust the permitted volume.

Comment: (continued) ... **It is strongly recommended to use this plugin only if there is hard need to do so**."  That bolding is from the rsyslog documentation, and that sure doesn't sound like "they play very well together at all.  I just spent several hours ripping journald **out** of a bunch of systems because it does not play well at all, even by itself.  Logging loads that took close to 300% using systemd's journal kludge are how handled by a single `rsyslogd` process that takes all of about 1/6th of a single CPU.

Comment: Hiya.  I've read all that, it's on the same page as the link in my previous comment WRT "tinkering with the rate limit".  The deal with corruption is I believe historical, "some versions" being ones prior to a fix, but I can't give you a reference.  What I can tell you is that I've been working on a network logging/messaging app that reads from an rsyslog output socket in order to exploit it's relatively simple field markup, and that's applied on various cloud servers that use `ForwardToSyslog` in `journald.conf`...

Comment: ...and [the rsyslog imuxsock module](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imuxsock.html), which is what is recommended **instead of** the `imjournal` module in the same paragraph as one you've quoted above, and there have been no issues with this for me in the year or so I've been working with it.  More recently I've done something using [the journald C API](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd-journal.html) to put stuff into SQLite databases for processing....

Comment: Because of that, I've gotten into the issue I think you mentioned earlier WRT not all journald output making it into rsyslog.  This is definitely true; for starters there are piles of metadata it keeps that aren't in the plain messages, and stuff like stderr output captured from systemd services (which appears in `systemd status` output)...

Comment: However, except for kernel messages and some highly integrated services like auditd that stuff does not come from applications feeding the logger; more detail about that in `man systemd.journald.fields`.  WRT it taking 300% CPU share, methinks the real issue there is upstream with the clients doing the logging, but I suppose that is a matter of context and opinion.

Comment: @goldilocks *WRT it taking 300% CPU share...* When you have to find an intermittent issue with one client system among hundreds using your service, you pretty much have to log everything you do.  systemd's journaling is not up to that.  But a simple, single `rsyslogd` process doesn't even break a sweat.

Comment: TBH I believe applications shouldn't use syslog exclusive of anything else if they tend to do lots of logging; that might as well be in its own file somewhere (although rsyslog does provide a means to do that, I dunno how great it would be if everything required an explicit if-then action in rsyslog), beyond that it seems like abuse not use of syslog (a la auditd).  But I won't claim that is a canonical opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling this service won't stop your device from functioning but logging will cease obviously. I see no other issues.

Comment: `"logging will cease obviously"` All logging - or just `journald` logging?

Comment: In modern Linux distros most services log to the system journal (`/dev/log`). Some don't use it but they are rare. The kernel keeps its own log in a memory buffer (`dmesg`) but it's limited and gets rotated.

Comment: Right - but what I'm asking is if `rsyslog` will continue "logging" as it does now. I don't want to stop `rsyslog` from logging - only `journald` because of its resource usage.

Comment: `rsyslog` itself is a logging server but if you had it installed with journald it doesn't log anywhere but redirects its messages to journald. You need to reconfigure it to make it actually log to `/var/log`.

Comment: Please read this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205883/understand-logging-in-linux

Comment: Thanks - a [good answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294206/286615) I thought. But here's a line from that answer: `Bad things happen system-wide if this program crashes, or the service is stopped.`  If `systemd-journald.service` isn't started at boot (because it's disabled), will "bad things" happen??

Comment: The "move to chat" nagging has begun, but one more comment: It doesn't seem that the `disable systemd-journald.service` does ***anything at all***. When I reboot, `journald` is started, and `systemctl status systemd-journald.service` reports it is running, loaded and active?! So - I do not see how this answers my question. What are your thoughts?

Comment: "only journald because of its resource usage": Sounds like you've found a journald bug? Journald is normally pretty OK in resource usage. Nothing to log, no load at all. The logging itself is fairly efficient. Is there maybe a problem you're trying to solve that might not actually have the "solution" of disabling a central piece of your operating system, but changing the way it works?

Comment: To be honest I see no issue with trying to disable logging altogether. There are multiple cases when it's completely redundant.

Comment: *"rsyslog itself is a logging server but if you had it installed with journald it doesn't log anywhere but redirects its messages to journald"* -> You have this backward.  Have a look at where most of `rsyslogd`'s open fd's point to -- files in `/var/log/journal/[machine-id]/` (the exact dir may be distro dependent).  And those are *read to* by it, not written by it; the writer is `journald` (see man systemd-journald FILES).

Comment: ...See also `man journald.conf` and the options to *send to*, not receive from, syslog. Also note that rsyslog by default is **not** configured to "redirect its messages to journald" (and AFAICT, can't directly).

Answer (score 0):

> How can journald be disabled?

First, this is what the [Rsyslogd documenation says about the `imjournal` module used to get log messages from systemd's journal](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/modules/imjournal.html) (bolding is original, italics are my emphasis):

> Note that this module reads the journal database, *what is considered a
> relatively performance-intense operation*. As such, the performance of
> a configuration utilizing this module may be *notably slower than when
> using imuxsock*. The journal provides imuxsock with a copy of all
> “classical” syslog messages, however, it does not provide structured
> data. Only if that structured data is needed, imjournal must be used.
> *Otherwise, imjournal may simply be replaced by imuxsock, and we highly
> suggest doing so*.
>
> We suggest to check out our short presentation on rsyslog journal
> integration to learn more details of anticipated use cases.
>
> **Warning**: Some versions of systemd journal have problems with database corruption, which leads to the journal to return the same
> data endlessly in a tight loop. This results in massive message
> duplication inside rsyslog probably resulting in a denial-of-service
> when the system resources get exhausted. This can be somewhat
> mitigated by using proper rate-limiters, but even then there are
> spikes of old data which are endlessly repeated. By default,
> ratelimiting is activated and permits to process 20,000 messages
> within 10 minutes, what should be well enough for most use cases. If
> insufficient, use the parameters described below to adjust the
> permitted volume. **It is strongly recommended to use this plugin only
> if there is hard need to do so**.

Do you have a "hard need" to feed "structured data" to rsyslog?  And go a lot slower while using significantly more CPU cycles while doing that?

Replacing systemd's journaling with straight-to-rsyslog is easy:

1. Edit `/etc/rsyslog.conf`.  Remove all references to `imjournal` and `imuxsock`.
2. Replace the above lines with

   `module(load="imuxsock"    # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)`
          `SysSock.Use="on")  # Turn on message reception via local log socket;`
3. Run the following command:

   `systemctl stop systemd-journal-flush.service systemd-journald.service systemd-journald-dev-log.socket systemd-journald.socket`
4. Run

   `systemctl stop systemd-journal-flush.service systemd-journald.service systemd-journald-dev-log.socket systemd-journald.socket`
5. Run

   `systemctl restart rsyslog`
6. Verify messages are appearing in `/var/log/messages` *et al*

You may need to tweak some of those commands - especially by disabling more systemd services.

Comment: *this is what the Rsyslogd documenation says about the imjournal module **used to get log messages** from systemd's journal* -> No, that's *a* module used to do such, and the documentation you quote recommends instead the [imuxsock](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imuxsock.html) module, which does not suffer from these problems and is much more the commonplace norm, I would guess (in fact I think it is the default on debian and derivations currently).

Comment: @goldilocks And without that "structured data", what does the entire systemd/journald pipeline add to logging?  While it sucks up stupendous amounts of CPU cycles to do a simple thing like *log data*?  Pitch it into a black hole where it belongs, never to bother the rest of the universe again.

Comment: If it isn't of interest or use to you, then you might as well not use it, of course.  Conversely, though, I'd say on the vast majority of systemd based systems the journal doesn't "suck up stupendous amounts of CPU cycles", so most people might as well leave it be.  The issue in the original question actually has to do with it being a storage pig, which is easy enough to limit in places where it becomes a problem.