# is it possible to prevent rsyslog messages going to systemd-journal log and how?

Tags: linux, iptables, rsyslog, systemd-journald

I have an iptables rule that is logging some of my networks activities into a log file using the `jump LOG` rule.

I filter the events to go to a specific file using the following rsyslog configuration file:

```
if $msg startswith '[ZN' then {
    action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/zn.log" template="RSYSLOG_FileFormat")
    stop
}
```

the filters works well, the messages do not go to the `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/kern.log` as expected, but I can see all of the messages by simply run `journalctl -f`

Is there any way to prevent the messages to get into the journal log? or does it coming earlier in the chain and can be filtered in other ways?

Comment: It's actually the other way around: Logs go to journalctl, and journalctl forwards them to rsyslog. See: [How can journald be disabled?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704833/how-can-journald-be-disabled)