# How can I create an infinite loop that kills a process if something is found in dmesg?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I need to create a `while` loop that if `dmesg` returns some/any value, then it should kill a determined process.

Here is what I have.

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ];
do

BUG=$(dmesg | grep "BUG: workqueue lockup" &> /dev/null)

    if [ ! -z "$BUG" ]; then
   killall someprocessname

else
    break
    fi
    done
```

I don't know if instead of `! -z` I should do `[ test -n "$BUG" ]`

I think with -n it says something about expecting a binary.

I don't know if the script will even work because the BUG lockup halts every process, but still there are few more lines in `dmesg` until the computer gets completely borked - maybe I can catch-up and kill the process.

Comment: You take the whole dmesg, so once one occurrence of the searched string occurs, you willn seee it each time, and thus  killall at each loop! (In addition to the other things @l0b0's mentionned such as the lack of sleeping/pacing, etc)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some issues:

- You are running this in a busy loop, which will consume as much resources as it can. This is one instance where `sleep`ing could conceivably be justified.
- However, [recent versions of `dmesg` have a flag to follow the output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/95852/3645), so you could rewrite the whole thing as (untested)

  ```
  while true
  do
      dmesg --follow | tail --follow --lines=0 | grep --quiet 'BUG: workqueue lockup'
      killall someprocessname
  done
  ```
- The code should be indented to be readable.
- It is really strange, but `[` is the same as `test` - see `help [`.

Comment: Did you mean to add `-q` so that `grep -q 'searchstring` exits from the `dmesg --follow` and thus let the next line be reached as soon as it sees one occurence of the search string? Without it your loop will not reach the killall nor loop?

Comment: And even with -q, I fear you'll killall a lot, if dmesg --follow shows a few lines of dmesg context (and thus shows the previous occurence(s)), hence my proposed aanswer as a variant.

Comment: @OlivierDulac The latter issue should be taken care of with the `tail`.

Comment: What does `tail --lines=0` do? I know what it means for any other value.

Comment: @Joe It's in the man page - with `--follow` it follows (that is, prints) only lines arriving after the command starts.

Answer (score 9):

A variant of @l0b0's answer:

```
dmesg --follow | awk '
   /BUG: workqueue lockup/  { system ("killall someprocessname") ; rem="done at each occurrence. You could add further things, like print to a logfile, etc.,"
        }'
```

This let's awk do the looping, which has some advantages:

- it will work until that process dies.
- It also do not call more than 1 `killall` per occurence of the searchstring "BUG: workqueue lockup", which improves upon the other answer.

To test: You can put this into a script named `thescript`, and do `nohup  thescript &`, so that `thescript` will keep running even after you quit your session.

Once you are satisfied it works, kill it, and then you can (instead of running it each time in a shell with `nohup`) transform it into a `daemon script` that you can then have started in your current runlevel.

ie: using another script as a model (you need to have at least the start,  stop and status sections), you can modify `thescript` appropriately and then place it within `/etc/rc.d/init.d`, and have a symlink to it named `Sxxthescript` under the appropriate(s) `/etc/rc.d/rcN`, `N` being a number for your normal runlevel (see the top lines of `who -a` to know the current run-level). And have the appropriate `Kxxthescript` symlinks too, in every (or almost every) runlevels, so that the script is appropriately killed when switching runlevels.

Or do "the appropriate things" to have it run/stopped via systemd or any equivalent system your distribution uses.

Comment: @Nobody: I am glad. Don't forget to "accept" (green checkmark) whichever answers seems the best in your opinion, unless you feel it needs to stay open to allow further answers (or modifications of the current answers).

Comment: both answers are correct wish I could select both.